# ngmin not working properly

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

My Grunt file looks like:

```
"use strict"

module.exports = (grunt) ->
  require("load-grunt-tasks") grunt
  # Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig
    appConfig:
      # configurable paths
      app: "app"
      server: "server"
      dist: "dist"

    # ngMin
    ngmin:
      dist:
        files: [
          cwd: '<%= appConfig.app %>/scripts'
          src: ['**/*.js']
          dest: ['<%= appConfig.dist %>/scripts']

        ]
```

But when I run it, I get:

```
Running "ngmin:dist" (ngmin) task
Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination `dest` should be a single folder, not a list:

```js
                dest: '<%= appConfig.dist() %>/scripts'
```

Not:

```js
                dest: [ '<%= appConfig.dist() %>/scripts' ]
```

Comment: ngmin will take care of copying all the JS files to the `dist` as well, right?